# Where am I wrong in the following?

Tags: matrices, inequality

We have matrix $D$ as follows $$\begin{bmatrix}
    d_{1,1} & d_{2,1} & d_{3,1}\\
    d_{1,2} & d_{2,2} & d_{3,2}\\
    d_{1,3} & d_{2,3} & d_{3,3}
  \end{bmatrix}.$$ For this matrix a research paper shows that the elements of the matrix follow following properties

1. Every entry is non-negative.
2. For every $1\leq j\leq 3$, $$\sum_{\tilde{k}=1}^3 d_{j,\tilde{k}}+\sum_{\tilde{j}=1,\tilde{j}\neq j}^3\max_k\{ d_{\tilde{j}k}\}\leq 1 \tag{1}.$$

After two pages the same research paper writes the second property as follows: $$\sum_{\tilde{k}}^{3}d_{j,\tilde{k}}+\max_k\left\{ \sum_{\tilde{j}=1,\tilde{j}\neq j}^3 d_{\tilde{j}k} \right\} \leq 1 \qquad \forall\ j\in\{1,2,3\}. \tag{2}$$

I tried to verify that left hand sides of (1) and (2) produce same results for $j = 1$, but (1) produces  $$\sum_{\tilde{k}=1}^3 d_{1,k}+\max\{d_{2,1},d_{2,2},d_{2,3}\}+\max\{d_{3,1},d_{3,2},d_{3,3}\}$$ while the left hand side of (2) produces $$\sum_{\tilde{k}=1}^3 d_{1,k}+\max\{d_{2,1}+d_{3,1},d_{2,2}+d_{3,2},d_{2,3}+d_{3,3}\}$$ which I think are not same. For example, consider the following matrix  $$D=\frac{1}{11}\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 3 & 2\\
    2 & 1 & 3\\
    3 & 2 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}.$$ For this matrix the (1) inequality is invalid while the (2) inequality is valid. Am I wrong somewhere or the left hand sides of (1) and (2) are not equal to each other. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your matrix entries are not as usual. Typically the first index in $M_{i,j}$ goes with the row number, the second with the column. (You revered this.)

Comment: @coffeemath yes you are right. But I think the inequalities does not depend on how the matrix is written.

Comment: @coffeemath for example $d_{32}$ will have same value no matter where we place it in the matrix and the value matters in the inequality.

Comment: @coffeemath but one thing that I found is that if the (2) is true then (1) is obviously true (because for example $\max\{d_{2,1}+d_{3,1},d_{2,2}+d_{3,2},d_{2,3}+d_{3,3}\}\leq \max\{d_{2,1},d_{2,2},d_{2,3}\}+\max\{d_{3,1},d_{3,2},d_{3,3}\}$). Perhaps this is the reason used in the paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second inequality is implied by the first.

This is because for each fixed $j$ ($1 \leq j \leq 3$), and every $\tilde{j},k$ ($1 \leq \tilde{j}, k \leq 3$) with $\tilde{j} \neq j$, we have
$$
\begin{alignat}{10}
& & d_{\tilde{j}k} &\leq \max_{1 \leq k \leq 3}\{ d_{\tilde{j}k} \}\\
\implies & & \sum_{\tilde{j} = 1, \tilde{j} \neq j}^3 d_{\tilde{j}k} &\leq
\sum_{\tilde{j} = 1, \tilde{j} \neq j}^3 \max_{1\leq k \leq 3}\{d_{\tilde{j}k}\} \\
\implies & & \max_{1 \leq k \leq 3} \left \{\sum_{\tilde{j} = 1, \tilde{j} \neq j}^3 d_{\tilde{j}k} \right\} &\leq
\sum_{\tilde{j} = 1, \tilde{j} \neq j}^3 \max_{1\leq k \leq 3}\{d_{\tilde{j}k}\}
\end{alignat}
$$

---

The first inequality is not implied by the second, as you have shown with the counterexample.